# How do I resolve python print error when running npm install --force

Tags: python-3.x, npm, npm-install, python-2.x, ubuntu-22.04

trying to run npm install --force on my ubuntu server
get the following error:

```
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python2 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:387:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-1004-aws
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
python version: Python 3.10.4
how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The only way to avoid it is not to try and install Python 2 code in a Python 3 environment. `print` statements went obsolete with Python 3.0 in 2007.

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/python2 --version` return?

Comment: @BoarGules The error message shows that `/usr/bin/python2` is invoked. Shouldn't that be a python2 interpreter?

Comment: Well, it isn't invoking a Python 2 interpreter.  That message is from Python 3.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install with NPM? And why does it require Python for its installation?

Comment: I'm getting this error on Windows also, two different machines. Just a standard NPM install.